# buddypress comment on profile

Tags: wordpress, profile, buddypress

I want to add the feature to buddypress that I can comment on each profile page,
Is there any plugin for this feature, or I have to edit the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this article: http://buddydev.com/buddypress/using-activity-as-wire-in-buddypress-1-2-themes/ in combination with this comment from Michal: http://buddydev.com/buddypress/using-activity-as-wire-in-buddypress-1-2-themes/#comment-19742.